# why can't I pass function arguments to dplyr select?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Easy question to explain:

This works great, so the dplyr usage feels correct, just selecting one column from iris, dropping duplicates and NAs:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- as_tibble(iris)

working <-data %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  drop_na()
print(working)
```

but let's say I want to generalise it in a function

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- as_tibble(iris)

myfunction <- function(inpdata,colname){
  thisres <- inpdata %>% 
    select(colname) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    drop_na()
  return(thisres)
}
print(myfunction(data,Sepal.Length))
```

this fails in the select statement, for some reason it resolves the argument Sepal.Length, but it doesn't recognise it as a valid object.

```
Error in `select()`:
! object 'Sepal.Length' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Please, since this will be a more elaborated manipulation of data that are not IRIS, don't reply with plain code alternatives, but, where possible, please do point me to documentation or explain me the rationale behind this is not working. This feels so easy hence quite frustrating :)

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html  "Data masking and tidy selection make interactive data exploration fast and fluid, but they add some new challenges when you attempt to use them indirectly such as in a for loop or a function."

Answer (score 2):

You should use the curly-curly `{{}}` operator. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

myfunction <- function(inpdata,colname){
  thisres <- inpdata %>% 
    select({{colname}}) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    drop_na()
  return(thisres)
}
print(myfunction(data,Sepal.Length))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 35 × 1
   Sepal.Length
          <dbl>
 1          5.1
 2          4.9
 3          4.7
 4          4.6
 5          5  
 6          5.4
 7          4.4
 8          4.8
 9          4.3
10          5.8
# … with 25 more rows
```